# How do I create Tagged Litetimes in Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

What I want is Simple Injector's equivalent of Autofac's [tagged lifetimes](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#tagging-a-lifetime-scope):

I've read Simple Injector's documentation. The most probable way to accomplishing this is by using Simple Injector's [custom lifestyles](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#customlifestyles):

But the documentation on it is very sparse and I can't figure out how to get what I want from it. How can I get the equivalent of Autofac's tagged scopes in Simple Injector?

Example of something I would want:

```cs
// Arrange
var container = new Container();

container.Register<ICommand, ConcreteCommand>(new AsyncScopedLifestyle());
container.Register<IDBContext, ConcreteDbContext>(new AsyncScopedLifestyle("dbContext"));

using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
{
    // Act
    var iCommandInstance1 = container.GetInstance<ICommand>();
    IDBContext iDbContextInstance1 = null;
    IDBContext iDbContextInstance2 = null;

    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container, "dbContext"))
    {
        var iCommandInstance2 = container.GetInstance<ICommand>();
        iDbContextInstance1 = container.GetInstance<IDBContext>();

        // Call things that depend on IDBContext here

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(iCommandInstance1, iCommandInstance2));
    }

    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container, "dbContext"))
    {
        var iCommandInstance3 = container.GetInstance<ICommand>();
        iDbContextInstance2 = container.GetInstance<IDBContext>();

        // Call things that depend on IDBContext here

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(iCommandInstance1, iCommandInstance3));
    }

    Assert.IsFalse(object.ReferenceEquals(iDbContextInstance1, iDbContextInstance2));
}
```

In my case it would not make sense to have the two `IDBContext` instances be the same.

Comment: There is no equivalent in Simple Injector. Please provide us with an example of what it is you are trying to achieve, and why.

Comment: @Steven Provided an example.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. Unfortunately, what you are describing is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you instead explain *the actual problem*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Injector does not support this feature. If you want to implement this feature manually with custom lifestyles, you'll have to rewrite a large part of Simple Injector. If you really want this feature, use AutoFac, or some other dependency injection framework that supports it.